# Are these parts from one set, lots of related sets or just a big messy jumble?

Tags: set-identification

I bought a job lot of approx 2kg of Lego at a (UK) car boot sale and I'm struggling to identify the set/s that the pieces relate to. The owner said that it belonged to her late husband and that she thought that they were...

> "...all from the same set".

There are four separated bags, all of which contain fairly similar parts, mostly yellow flat plates and small black pieces with lots of large tracks and propellers. I've snapped the most obviously unusual pieces in each bag.

**Bag 1:**

[image]
[image]

**Bag 2:**

[image]
[image]

**Bag 3:**

[image]
[image]

**Bag 4:**

[image]
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: adding the approximate piece count (or weight) could help determine if you have more pieces then would ever be in one set.

Comment: @David - Just under 1.6kg. TBH, I was pretty sure they were from multiple sets.

Answer (score 2):

They are definitely not from a single set, as the 16x16 yellow plate was only ever sold in [Friends sets](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-6035620), that do not contain any Technic track pieces.

Another telltale sign is the transparent orange Brick with Shaft 1x8x1, whose only occurrence is in a [few Star Wars podracer and Alpha Team sets from 1999-2001](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-4164064), none of which has any propeller pieces.

The first picture contains a black turbine insert with many blades, this was sold in [many unrelated](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-4192455) [sets across the years](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-6088638).

Comment: I've seen it elsewhere; http://www.peeron.com/inv/sets/4128-1?showpic=11851

Comment: Nice find, but that set contains a [yellow, 16x16 baseplate](https://rebrickable.com/parts/3867/baseplate-16-x-16/14/), whose thickness and rounded corners set it apart from a 16x16 plate (best seen on your Bag 4 photo).

Comment: This one seems unusual; https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgtxY.jpg. That any help?

Comment: That's a [chain wheel](https://brickset.com/parts/4544529/chain-wheel-%C3%B825-8-dec), decorated with a pattern used in the [2009 wave of the Bionicle line](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-4544529)

Comment: So to answer your question, these are just a big messy jumble of LEGO parts :)

Comment: Yes, I'm certainly getting that impression. I suppose it was too much to hope that they were part of one enormous (and expensive) set :-)

Answer (score 2):

[Sprocket, Ø40,7](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-6019617) in white only comes in 1 set:

[42065-1: RC Tracked Racer](https://brickset.com/sets/42065-1/RC-Tracked-Racer)
[image]

[Plate 16X16](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-6035620) and [Plate 6X6 W. Bow](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-6054414) in cool yellow only come together in 1 set:

[41035-1: Heartlake Juice Bar](https://brickset.com/sets/41035-1/Heartlake-Juice-Bar)

[image]

Thanks to Zovits for identifying [Chain Wheel, Ø25,8, Dec.](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-4544529) as this part only comes in 1 set together with [4528407: Sprocket, Ø40,7](https://brickset.com/parts/4528407/sprocket-%C3%B840-7) in bright orange:

[8996-1: Skopio XV-1](https://brickset.com/sets/8996-1/Skopio-XV-1)

[image]

[Propeller Ø71.84](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-4262976) in Reddish Brown also only comes in 1 set:

[7260-1: Wookiee Catamaran](https://brickset.com/sets/7260-1/Wookiee-Catamaran)

[image]

Comment: Ah. This would explain all the track